# Overlap of scope between money.SE and quant.SE?

Tags: discussion

As many of you may be aware, we just entered public beta on the [quantitative finance stackexchange site](https://quant.stackexchange.com/), which is for:

> professionals and traders working in
>   investment banking, and academics
>   involved in teaching and research.

I see potential for issues in questions being asked on either of our sites when the other is more appropriate.  Ultimately, we should have a migration path.  But in the meantime, I'd love to get everyone's feedback on how we should distinguish between our two communities.  Here's an example of question on our meta site that sparked this for me:

- https://quant.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81/are-retail-trading-questions-in-scope

Comment: if it was done properly, only hft questions would stay on the quant site since they're all usable by anyone on this site

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's going to be some overlap, but I think the easiest way to know what is on topic there vs. here is that questions over there are mostly interesting to people **working in the finance industry**.

Day traders could probably ask questions on both sites, but the quant will always require that you **already** know about a lot of financial related jargon and know how.  Based on the existing scope of the questions on this site, money.stackexchange.com is finance for people that do not work in the finance industry. In other words, the answers relate to their life, not their job.

I have no hope of ever answering any question on the quant site, and I'd prefer that it stays that way.  When I hit the front page of that site, I want to see words that I don't understand because I know I'm not a quant.

Comment: Just to agree with Michael here... there might be questions accidentally mis-posted, but there is almost NO overlap between the two categories. It's molecular biology vs. cooking, basically.

Comment: @JoelSpolsky lol like what?  i haven't seen a serious question on that site that isn't usable by anyone on this site.  maybe one day they'll get a real hft quant to post, but until then, it's superfluous.